# Wave equation of string with mass and special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, waves

Suppose I have a string with uniformly distributed mass $\mu$. The instant before I introduce a perturbation which produces a wave, Bob adds an additional mass $M$ a distance $x$ from my end of the string. Now it seems like the wave must initially behave as if the additional mass has not been added yet, or else I would know that Bob has inserted the mass instantly, violating the fundamental postulate that no information travels faster than the speed of light. For example, if I measure the initial velocity of the wave, then would I measure the wave velocity of a wave with no additional mass? Would this velocity then abruptly change after time $\frac{x}{c}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of light affects some things in the string, but there is more to it.

Atoms in the string exert forces on each other. If you pull on one, it pulls on the next, which pulls on the next, etc. This is what holds the string together. If you pull on one end, the other end will follow because of this.

The forces between atoms are electromagnetic. Disturbances to these fields travel at the speed of light. So the neighbor feels a change in the force almost immediately. But the the neighbor doesn't follow instantly. It takes time to accelerate. It is like pulling on one end of a Slinky. The disturbance travels up the string, and then the other end follows.

It isn't quite like a Slinky, because a Slinky is a very loose spring. It is made so disturbances travel slowly. If you pull on a string the other end receives the news much more quickly. It takes about as much time as for a pulse of sound to travel down the string. A disturbance on a string can't travel faster than sound in the string.

Sound travels much slower than light. This is reasonable. It takes time for each atom to accelerate. And the atoms never travel anywhere near the speed of light.

---

This is all good. But if you pluck a string, this disturbance travels down the string at a speed much slower than the speed of sound.

When you pluck a string, you are pulling sideways on the string. You are bending it. If you bend a limp string, the other end just sits there. It might be helpful to think of a chain, which does the same thing.

Suppose you hang one end of a chain from a nail. Gravity is trying to pull the chain down, and the nail is holding it up. Or rather, the top link is holding the next link, and that link is holding its neighbor, and so on. This is something new. The chain is being stretched. There is a force of tension in the chain.

Now if you pluck the chain, the disturbance travels down the chain. If you pull a link A sideways, the tension from its neighbor B pulls back on it. This does two things. The force on the A gets A moving in a direction back toward being lined up. But every force has an equal and opposite force. B feels a force from A, which pulls B out of alignment. This repeats when B pulls on C, and so forth.

You can see two things that will make a difference to how fast the disturbance travels. First, how big are the forces of tension. If you pull the ends of the chain apart more strongly, there are larger forces pushing links around. The links will accelerate more quickly and the speeds will be larger.

The other is the mass of each link. A larger mass makes the links accelerate more slowly. The speeds will be lower.

It is the same with a string. You have to stretch a string to make a disturbance travel. More tension means it will travel faster. And a fatter more massive string will vibrate more slowly.

You can see this in a violin, guitar, piano, harp, and so on. The bass strings are fatter so they vibrate more slowly. You tune the instrument by changing the tension. More tension makes a higher pitch.

---

Getting back to your original question, it doesn't matter if Bob puts the mass in just as you pluck. It can be there in advance. The disturbance will travel down the string at a rate determined by the mass of the string and the tension. The mass won't affect the motion or be affected by it until the motion arrives.

Answer (score 0):

The time $x/c$ is not particularly meaningful in this scenario. The mass density of the string is still $\mu$ and the wave propagation speed will still be determined by that. When the wave reaches $x$ then at $x$ the different wave speed at that point will produce a bit of reflection and a bit of transmission. The reflected and transmitted waves will each continue propagating at the original speed.

Comment: but doesn't the derivation of the wave propagation speed depend on the fact that the tension in the string is constant? Here we cannot have constant tension in the string due to the added mass right?

Comment: The mass doesn’t necessarily change the tension. However, if you wanted then you could have Bob change the tension by pulling on the opposite end of the string.